# scala-arm: Expression of type Iterator[Int] doesn't conform to expected type ManagedResource[B_]

Tags: scala, scala-arm

This code using `"com.jsuereth" %% "scala-arm" % "2.0"`:

```
import resource._
val lineLengths = for {
  source <- managed(scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt"))
  line <- source.getLines()
} yield line.length
```

Fails compiling with error:

```
Expression of type Iterator[Int] doesn't conform to expected type ManagedResource[B_]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Could you try out what `val lineLengths = managed(scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt")).map(_.getLines.map(_.length))` says?

Comment: this compiles, and IntelliJ says that lineLengths is of type `ExtractableManagedResource[Iterator[Int]]`. However, `val lineLengths = managed(scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt")).flatMap(_.getLines)` fails compiling with `Type mismatch, expected BufferedSource => ManagedResources[NotInferredB], actual: BufferedSource => Iterator[String]`

Comment: I simplified the last example, and I am not using `.length`. I was expecting the last example to return the list of lines: `val lines: Iterator[String] = for { source <- managed(scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt")); line <- source.getLines() } yield line`